# Как найти средние значение по каждому столбцу и добавить результат в конец?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, обработка-данных

У меня есть `DataFrame` считанный с Excel. Мне надо найти средние значение по каждому столбцу. Потом добавить результат в конец.

Не могу понять как добавить в конец результаты.

```
import pandas

excel_data_dl = pandas.read_excel('example.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Sheet1')
ALRS = excel_data_dl['ALRS'].tolist()
ROLO = excel_data_dl['ROLO'].tolist()
ISKJ = excel_data_dl['ISKJ'].tolist()
GAZP = excel_data_dl['GAZP'].tolist()
LSRG = excel_data_dl['LSRG'].tolist()
PIKK = excel_data_dl['PIKK'].tolist()
SBER = excel_data_dl['SBER'].tolist()
MOEX = excel_data_dl['MOEX'].tolist()
MGNT = excel_data_dl['MGNT'].tolist()
GCHE = excel_data_dl['GCHE'].tolist()

sr_znach_ALRS = sum(ALRS)/len(ALRS)
sr_znach_ROLO = sum(ROLO)/len(ROLO)
sr_znach_ISKJ = sum(ISKJ)/len(ISKJ)
sr_znach_GAZP = sum(GAZP)/len(GAZP)
sr_znach_LSRG = sum(LSRG)/len(LSRG)
sr_znach_PIKK = sum(PIKK)/len(PIKK)
sr_znach_SBER = sum(SBER)/len(SBER)
sr_znach_MOEX = sum(MOEX)/len(MOEX)
sr_znach_MGNT = sum(MGNT)/len(MGNT)
sr_znach_GCHE = sum(GCHE)/len(GCHE)
```

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте так:

```
excel_data_dl = pandas.read_excel('example.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
res = excel_data_dl.append(excel_data_dl.mean(), ignore_index=True)
```

PS весь остальной ваш код можно убрать...